# Which bayesian filter will be the cheapest in Python?

Tags: python, bayesian-networks, spam-prevention

Long story short, I am trying to filter non-email text (small books actually) as bad (spam) and good (ham). I was preparing to use bogofilter (http://bogofilter.sourceforge.net/) as it seems both mature and effective, however I have been writing my code in Python; this means that I will probably have to use subprocess to call bogofilter from within my script as it is written in (C?). 
I just came across a python based spam filter that seems to do what I need https://github.com/jart/redisbayes (though I haven't tested the effectiveness of one versus the other. I don't have a nice dataset yet). It uses a redis key backend that seems all well and good, however I am unfamiliar with redis and am not sure what it's advantages/disadvantages would be versus subprocess calls to bogofilter (which is BerkleyDB backed). I understand that redis is actually a server process, and therefore it seems that I would have to have an instance running before my script starts. That wouldn't be too much of a problem, but the end goal is to have this running on my Uni's servers; bogofilter on the otherhand has no ongoing background processes that require my attention.

It comes down to 1: performance (which truth be told isn't the end of the world, this dataset  is something in the range of 100k-400k short lines of text; about 50 MB worth), 2: practicality not only from the programmers standpoint (me!) but the sysadmin later on, and 3: model reliablity (I plan on looking at the bogofilter algorithm in a bit here as I understand that it is not just a bayesian model... I think. I'm new to the Machine Learning arena).

I just wanted some thoughts about the smartest course of action, and to maybe help the next guy doing something slightly obscure like this. Lowly undergrad open to suggestions, hit me!

Comment: FYI, [SpamBayes](http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/) is all Python.  Had wide adoption, especially among Outlook users.  Gary Robinson wrote an [article about the math in Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6467).